# waiting for the device to come online Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android

Suddenly my Android emulator closed and stop working. Now, the following message is always displayed whenever I run the emulator:

> waiting for the device to come online

I have tried everything to get the emulator running but haven't found a solution yet. Please help

**Specification of my laptop if helpful to you:**

- I have window 10
- 8 GB RAM
- 2 GB graphic card

Comment: Did you recently update your Android Studio?

Comment: yes in fact  i regularly update

Comment: You might want to go to SDK Tools under your settings and check if your Android Emulator option is updated and checked.

Comment: yes that option is updated and checked

Comment: Meet this problem too.

Comment: Do you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After the update my Emulator version, I got the same problem.
go to `setting -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> check your Android Emulator` if it is unchecked. hope it helps.